# Adding Pooling and Port details in Connection String

Tags: .net, mysql, mysql5

My application is built on VS-2008 and using MySQL Server 5.5.15. It is a desktop application and running on a single PC with MySQL Server installed on the same PC.

The application has been running well from over six months but from last two days I am getting a strange error when I try to open a report. The error image is below:

[image]

I searched for a solution on the Internet and found that it has to do with the Max TCP/IP ports defined in the registry. Few solutions also recommended to define port number in the connection string and some suggested to use connection pooling.

Adding port number in the connection string did solve my problem, but I want to make sure that connection string is correct to deal with this issue in future.

My present connection string looks like:

```
server=localhost;Port=3306;user id=root;password=myPassword;database=test;Allow Zero Datetime=True
```

I want to add connection pooling details and also want to better define **localhost**.

I also got few suggestions to replace **user id** with **uid**.

What changes are required to fix the error I am getting?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add Pooling=True to your connection string:

```
server=localhost;Port=3306;user id=root;password=myPassword;database=test;Allow Zero Datetime=True;Pooling=True;
```

Here's a list of Connection String examples for MySQL that might point you in the right direction:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Additionally, you could try the resolution in this post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/cebd7a1d-724e-45a6-8e10-fdfdc5fcfd04

Comment: Tried but it is also net helping.

Comment: Are you closing the connection to your database after querying it?

Comment: Once the records get transferred to the Dataset, I am closing the connection.

Comment: Has a password expired, firewall been enabled or Anti-virus been installed lately.

Having a look about, setting the port seems to be the only valid solution, unless anyone else has an answer.

Comment: Password not expired. AV installed without firewall. Tried uninstalling AV and firewall both.

Comment: In this instance I think the setting of the port number will be fine and should be future proof.

Comment: With regards to the localhost part of the string, you could change that to the IP address of the server MySql is on.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reinstall VS, try to use the latest build with .NET MySQL connector with a lot of new features like editing or run your query from VS, and some other suggest to check Winsock setting [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259)

Also, it may happened due to network problem, or there is recently a software installed that interact with network packets.